# Flatten IEnumerable in EFcore using linq

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core

I am attempting to flatten an `IEnumerable` in EF Core but I get an error on the `SelectMany`:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<WellDataTableViewModel>> GetWellsForDataTable() =>
            await context.Wells
            .Include(x => x.Pad)
            .ThenInclude(x => x.Tract)
            .Include(x => x.WellOperations)
            .ThenInclude(x => x.Lessee)
            .Select(p => new WellDataTableViewModel
             {
                WellId = p.Id,
                ApiNum = p.ApiNum,
                WellNum = p.WellNum,
                PadName = p.Pad.PadName,
                TractNum = p.Pad.Tract.TractNum,
                LesseeName = p.WellOperations.SelectMany(x => x.Lessee.LesseeName)
            })
            .ToListAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
```

This is the error:

> Error CS0266
> Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable' to 'string'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)
> Minerals  C:\tfsmappings\Minerals-development\Minerals\Repositories\WellRepository.cs 33  Active

Here is the viewmodel class I am attempting to populate:

```
public class WellDataTableViewModel
{
        public long WellId { get; set; }
        public string WellNum { get; set; }
        public string ApiNum { get; set; }
        public string PadName { get; set; }
        public string TractNum { get; set; }
        public string LesseeName { get; set; }
}
```

`WellOperations` is an `IEnumerable` on wells and each well operation has a Lessee which holds he `lesseeName` of type string

in the wells class I have

```
public IEnumerable<WellOperation> WellOperations { get; set; }
```

in well operation I have a lessee which contains the lesseeName

```
public class WellOperation
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public Single? OpShare { get; set; }
    public bool? ReportsTotal { get; set; }
    public string Notes { get; set; }
    public long? LesseeId { get; set; }
    public Lessee Lessee { get; set; }
    public long? WellId { get; set; }
    public Well Well { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: That `SelectMany` returns a `IEnumerable<char>` not a `string`.  You need to decide how to combine all those names into one string.  Like maybe `string.Join(", ", p.WellOperations.Select(x => x.Lessee.LesseeName))`.

Comment: perhaps what you intend to do is **p.WellOperations.Single(x=>x.WellId==p.Id).Lessee.LesseeName**

Comment: so is there no way to make a new row for each of the objects in the collection. like if there are 2 items in well operations it would create two of my viewmodels instead of a concactenated string?

Comment: `p.WellOperations.SelectMany(x => x.Lessee.LesseeName)` makes no sense - returns enumerable of characters. you probably want to flatten the whole wells set, e.g. context.Wells.SelectMany(w => w.WellOperations, (well, op => new WellDataTableViewModel { ... })`  Or start the query from `context.Set<WellOperation>()` followed by `Select` and use the navigation properties.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, do not use `Include(s)`, if you have full custom projection via Select, they do nothing instead of complicating LINQ query parsing :

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<WellDataTableViewModel>> GetWellsForDataTable()
{
    var query = 
       from w in context.Wells
       from wo in w.WellOperations
       select new WellDataTableViewModel
       {
          WellId = w.Id,
          ApiNum = w.ApiNum,
          WellNum = w.WellNum,
          PadName = w.Pad.PadName,
          TractNum = w.Pad.Tract.TractNum,
          LesseeName = wo.Lessee.LesseeName
        });

    return await query.ToListAsync();
}
```